# AngularJS: $http does not work to outer API

Tags: angularjs

```
myApp.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
    delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
 }]);

$http.defaults.useXDomain = true;

$http.get('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=asp+site:codehint.ru').
    success(
        function (data, status, headers, config) {
            alert('answer');
        }
   );
```

Is not working! Because: Origin \site name\ is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

I have just started using AngularJS and forced to use $.getJSON because it is working fine in situation above. Can anybody show me the right solution of code above to make an AJAX call to outer services like Google?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try [$http.jsonp](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http#jsonp) instead.

You'll just have to add `callback=JSON_CALLBACK` to your request:

```
$http.jsonp('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=asp+site:codehint.ru&callback=JSON_CALLBACK')
```